# sending json data using curl php

Tags: json

I want to send data using php,curl. I have de following code with the string containing the data :

```
     <?php
     $string='
     {
        "unidad": [
     { "baterias": { "bat1": "10", "bat2": "18", "bat3": "13", "bat4": "18" }              },
     { "lineas": { "line1": "110", "line2": "128", "line3":         "130", "line4": "125" } },
     { "ampers": { "amp1": "10", "amp2": "7", "amp3": "13" }
     }
     ]
     }';

    $jsonDataEncoded=json_encode($string,true);
    $curl_connection = curl_init('http://172.27.17.210:81/recv_json.php');
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible;       MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
   curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-Type:    application/json'));
    curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $jsonDataEncoded);
    $result = curl_exec($curl_connection);
    echo $result;
    curl_close($curl_connection);
    ?>
```

and I have de following php file to process the data :

```
enter code here


<html>
<body>
<?php
$json_input_data=json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'),TRUE);
echo gettype($json_input_data)."\n";
echo $json_input_data;
?>
</body>
</html>
```

The result is string, I want to know how to convert the string to an array so I can access the fields contained in it.

Thanks